# Understanding lyrics of song "游京"

Tags: translation, lyrics, songs

Despite being a very lovely song, I'm having a little trouble understanding some of the lyrics to the song “游京.”

In line (3), I understand individually the words 人, 杂乱, 戏, and 小丑, but I don't really understand what they are trying to communicate together. "People recklessly act as clowns" (i.e. - foolish) is my best guess, but that doesn't really seem right given the vibe of the remaining lines.

In line (9), I understand individually the words 盼, 郎君, 几, 撩, 纱 individually, but I'm also not entirely clear on what they are trying to communicate together. My best guess is "I am looking forward to my husband's various lifts of the veil." Is this potentially a euphemism?

In line (10), the singer is talking about staying 夜泊借宿 at a... restaurant 酒家? Not a 酒楼?

In line (11), is 君 referring to the 郎君 of line (9)? i.e. - the husband?

In line (12), I understand 威风凛凛 to mean "awe-inspring" or "impressive," but I don't understand the meaning intended by combining thi with 寻他, which I am interpreting as"search for him."

In line (13), I don't understand the meaning of 本 in this sentence. Perhaps is "我本"merely a way of referring to one's self?

In line (15), I also understand 不舍, 笑声, and 离它 individually, but I am having trouble piecing together the full meaning. "I am reluctant to leave it (京) laughing/with the sound of laughter" doesn't seem right.

Thank you so much for any assistance and clarity you can provide!

我走在长街中 (1)

听戏子唱京城 (2)

人杂乱戏小丑 (3)

叶黄退入长秋 (4)

悠悠的古城中 (5)

听美人奏琴声 (6)

朗朗夜色星空 (7)

望孩童放花灯 (8)

盼郎君几撩纱 (9)

夜泊借宿酒家 (10)

君载着黑骏马 (11)

威风凛凛寻他 (12)

我本一醉天涯 (13)

游走京惜繁华 (14)

不舍笑声离它 (15)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OS2SfSHz3aU

Answer (score 2):

我走在长街中 (1) - I walk in a long street

听戏子唱京城 (2) - listen to a street performer sings about the capital city

人杂乱戏小丑 (3) - chaotic crowd, clowns acting

叶黄退入长秋 (4) - leaves turn yellow, and retreat into a long autumn (they will fall and disappear like a retreating army)

悠悠的古城中 (5) - in this mellow old city

听美人奏琴声 (6) - listen to the sound of a beauty playing guqin

朗朗夜色星空 (7) - clear night starry sky

望孩童放花灯 (8) - watch children releasing lanterns

盼郎君几撩纱 (9) - hoping for my handsome to lift the gauze curtain (which I was in behind) to see me

夜泊借宿酒家 (10) - At night I rent a room at an inn

君载着黑骏马 (11) - you ride a beautiful black horse

威风凛凛寻他 (12) - So majestic is you whom I seek

我本一醉天涯 (13) - I was naturally a world wanderer without a goal

游走京惜繁华 (14) - visit the capital and enjoy the bustling

不舍笑声离它 (15) - Can't bear to leave the laughter but I have to leave it behind

Lyrics are often ungrammatical:

*(3)in "戏小丑" 戏 is the verb; 小丑 in the subject*

*(8) 放花灯 releasing lanterns  (to the sky or down on the river)*

*(9) 撩纱 short for 撩起紗簾 (lift the gauze curtain)*

*(12) 威风凛凛 = majestic; 寻他 = seek him --> He is so majestic, (I must) seek him*

*(13) 一醉天涯 = drunkenly (aimlessly)  wandering the world*

*(14)惜 short of 珍惜 = to treasure --> to enjoy*

(*15) 不舍笑声 = can't bear to leave the laughter;  离它 = leave it --> Even I can't bear to leave the laughter, I have to leave it behind*

Answer (score 1):

The song seems to describe the experience of a character touring the capital city during the "Loi Krathong Festival" (水灯节). The experience and feeling are fully described by lines other than lines (9), (11), and (12), which sidetracked the main theme and involved a third person - a young maid.

My interpretation:

line (3), 人杂乱戏小丑 - 人蛇雜混的人群中還有小丑在演出 (the place filled with people of all kinds, among them, there is a performing clown. The sentence describes the scene of a lively festival.)

line (8), 望孩童放花灯 - 看到玩花燈的孩子們

line (9), 盼郎君几撩纱 - 期盼着如意郎君早日來迎娶 (新婚之夜郎君挑起新娘的頭紗, here means "wish to get married soon to give birth to a child like the lantern playing kids she saw")

line (10), 夜泊借宿**酒家** (酒家 = 客棧)

line (11), 君**载**着黑骏马 = 君**乘**着黑骏马 (载，乘也。——《说文》)

line (12), 威风凛凛寻他 - 快去尋找那(乘着黑骏马)威风凛凛的他

line (13), 我本一醉天涯 - 我本是流蕩的天涯過客

line (15), 不舍笑声离它 - 不舎得京城的笑鬧暄嘩但還是得離開它